# Multiple hidden divs to be shown

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a series of images, behind each of which I have a `div` with `absolute` positioning.
I'm looking for a way to use jQuery, with one bit of code as short and sweet as possible to enable me to show the otherwise hidden `div`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#image1').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#imageDescriptor1').show('fast');
    });

    $('#image1').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#imageDescriptor1').hide('fast');
        $('#imageDescriptor1').clearQueue();
    });
});
```

Obviously in an ideal world, I'd rather not have to repeat the code 5 times; and the text in the `imageDescriptor`is unique too obviously.
Is there something glaringly obvious I've missed here? Perhaps a way to use `$(this)` from behind the image?  Thanks in advance!

```
#imageDescriptor1, #imageDescriptor2, #imageDescriptor3, #imageDescriptor4, #imageDescriptor5{
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:50px;
z-index:50;
display:none;
padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
background-color:#f3be05;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
max-width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Is there any link between a div and an image ? Can you post a sample of the HTML output, please ?

Comment: can you show us your html? Maybe create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? If I can see the html this may just be a selector fix or something even simpler.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of actual images. Hope this is enough to go on!

http://jsfiddle.net/V2rCn/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your Fiddle example you can do this:

- First assign a class for the `footerBox` divs and for the `imageDescriptor` divs, this to make refference for the Jquery function:

  ```
  <div id="footerBox1" class="box">
     <div id="imageDescriptor1" class="inside">
  ```
- After you can refference the function with those `class names` and use the `hover()` handler:

  ```
  $('.box').hover(
      function(){
        $('.inside',this).show('fast');
      },
      function(){
        $('.inside',this).hide('fast').clearQueue();
  });
  ```

See the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/V2rCn/11/**

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and give your HTML elements classes:

HTML like so:

```
<img class="image" />
<p class="descriptor">[...]</p>
```

jQuery Javascript like so (you can include this in DOM ready as in your example):

```
$(".image").on( "hover", function(){ // mouse enter
    $(this).closest(".descriptor").show('fast');
}, function(){ // mouse leave
    $(this).closest(".descriptor").hide('fast').clearQueue();
});
```

Comment: `closest()` searches up the DOM tree so it will work only if the description is an ancestor of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can select an image using its' class (which will apply to all your images) and then traverse the DOM to find the right description using either:

- `find()` or `children()` if the description is a descendant of the image
- `closest()` or `parent()` if the description is an ancestor of the image
- `next()` if the description is a sibling of the image
- or a combination of those above if the DOM structure is more complicated

e.g.

```
$('.image').mouseenter(function() { 
    $(this).find('.description').show(); 
});
```